# Report Viewer problem on WinForms: Some parameters or credentials have not been specified

Tags: c#, reportviewer, subreport

I am trying to implement an application that displays a report using the report viewer on Windows Form. The report also consists of a sub report.

Without the sub report, I am able to display the report with no problems. However, after I added the sub-report in, I receive the error "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified".

I have implemented in the following manner: I call on the SubreportProcessingEventHandler before adding the datasource to my parent report. In the event of a SubreportProcessing, I will add the datasource for the subreport.

I have also tried implementing with a sub report that does not need any parameters. However, I still receive the same error "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified".

Is there any mistakes which I have made? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error although it wasn't related to subreports.

I made the error go away by changing

`ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh`

To

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence)
```

NOTE: In report viewer 2010 it says this method is obsolete but it seems to work OK in my tests so far.